# Implement a matrix with another matrix in F#

Tags: f#, matrix

I have the first matrix which should account for each users (in lines) which products (in columns) they like.
Let's take 3 users and 5 products.
No user liked a product, so my matrix ILike equals a nul matrix :

```
let matrixILike = [[0.; 1.;2.;3.]
                   [1.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [2.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [3.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [4.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [5.;0.;0.;0.]]
```

Now  user 1 likes product 2 and user 3 likes product 5 which can be summarized in the following matrix:

```
let matrixAction = [[1.;2.]
                    [3.;5.]]
```

So I would like to implement the matrix ILike thanks to the matrixAction to obtain a new updated matrixILike like this :

```
let matrixILike = [[0.; 1.;2.;3.]
                   [1.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [2.;1.;0.;0.]
                   [3.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [4.;0.;0.;0.]
                   [5.;0.;0.;1.]]
```

I try to do this with a "match with" code but it is not working.

```
for k = 0 to matrixAction.NumRows - 1 do
            match  (matrixAction.[k,0] , matrixAction.[k,1]) with
            | (matrixILike.[x,0] , matrixILike.[0,y]) -> (matrixILike.[x,y] <- 1.)
            | _ -> (matrixILike.[x,y] <- 0.)
matrixILike
```

If you have any suggestions I take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your input parameters, this function will do the job.

```
let update actions = 
    let mapiTail f = function 
                     | []   -> [] 
                     | h::t -> h :: List.mapi (f h) t
    mapiTail (fun matHead _ ->
        mapiTail (fun rowHead i x -> 
            if List.exists ((=) [matHead.[i+1];rowHead]) actions then 1. else x))
```

Usage:

```
update matrixAction matrixILike
```

It uses List.mapi which is the same as List.map but with additional parameter: the index.

Comment: Thank you Gustavo, very impressive. Thanks also to Daniel very helpful

Answer (score 4):

This is trivial if you change `matrixILike` to an array.

```
let matrixILike = [|
  [|0.;1.;2.;3.|]
  [|1.;0.;0.;0.|]
  [|2.;0.;0.;0.|]
  [|3.;0.;0.;0.|]
  [|4.;0.;0.;0.|]
  [|5.;0.;0.;0.|]
|]

let matrixAction = [
  (1., 2.)
  (3., 5.)
]

matrixAction
|> List.iter (fun (u, p) -> matrixILike.[int p].[int u] <- 1.)
```

Comment: Not necessarily functional, but beautiful :)

Comment: Thank you Daniel, indeed it is ok (and beautiful) but my example is too trivial... If the Users ID (in my previous example 1, 2 and 3 in the matrixILike) does not correspond to the index of the rows/colums of the matrixILike (for example userID 10, 3, 1100), do you have an idea? That's why I tried to  use a "match with"... but it s not working

Comment: I think, in that case, a dictionary of dictionaries would be your best bet. Conceptually, something like `Dictionary<User, Dictionary<Product, float>>`. A `DataTable` would also work.